# How to get the output of the first item in your query in Velocity

Tags: velocity

How do you get the output of the first item in your query in Velocity. For example, if your query is $Items and contains many objects, how do you get the first one?

I tried $Items(1) but it is not the answer. Any suggestions? Thank you.

Comment: Did you try using indexed notation as in the Velocity docs?! That'd be what I'd try first. It also depends entire on what the actual object *type* is, which we can't really guess.

Comment: Yeah, I browsed through the Velocity developer guide, but did not get a very clear answer. I thought it might be an easy solution, but may be dependent on the object type as you said. I'll try reviewing the guide more thoroughly. =/

Comment: Hmm. http://velocity.apache.org/engine/devel/user-guide.html#index

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In most programming languages, [the first element in a vector is `0`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero-based_numbering), not `1`.

In most programming languages, round brackets mean function invocation, square brackets mean accessing an indexed position from a vector. So, try `$Items[0]`.

Also, Velocity is just a wrapper for real java objects. So, if your `$Items` object is indeed array-like, you should use the [standard accessor method for Java lists](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/List.html#get%28int%29): `$Items.get(0)`.

Comment: Cool beans!  I was banging my head against a wall trying to figure this out and your explanation helped greatly.  The `Items.get(0)` signature worked perfectly for my use case.  Thanks @Sergiu!